# c++ iterate multiple ordered collections of different types

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

Are there any parts of the standard library that would support the following use case:
You have N collections, with each collection potentially being a type of collection (C1, C2 ..., Cn) all of which support `begin()`, `end()` and iteration, ie (vector, deque, etc).

Each of these collections can contain a objects of different types ie, collections are C1, C2, C3, and are of different sizes.

In addition, all of these types can be ordered via a timestamp, but the way that each of these items store a timestamp is different. For example, type A has member `A.timestamp`, B has a member `B.TimeStamp`, C has a function `C.GetTimestamp()`.

Each of the collections are already ordered by this function.

What I want to do is iterate over all items in all collections, in order, using the order functions, and call another function, i.e. a visit function, `std::function<void(A &)>` for collections of A, `std::function<void(B&)>` for items of type B, etc.

I then want to, make calls for each item in timestamp order. For example:

```
class A
{
   public:
      time_t timeStamp;
      int  length;
};

class B
{
    public:
    B(time_t _tm, std::string _name):timestamp(_tm), name(_name){}
    time_t GetTimestamp() { return timeStamp; }
    std::string GetName() { return name; }
private:
    time_t timeStamp;
    std::string name;
}

std::vector<A> listA {1, 4}, {5, 7}, {8,9});

std::deque<B>  listB { B(0,"bob"), B(3, "Frank") };

// iterate over listA and listB in time sequential order
// for items in A call [](const A&a) { std::cout << a.length << std::endl; }
// for items in B call [](const B&b) { std::cout << b.name << std::endl; }
// Output would be:
// bob
// 4
// Frank
// 7
// 9
```

My thought on implementation would be to, define a base class which is templated by the type that the ordering function returns:

```
template<classname O>
class VisitedCollection
{
   public:
      virtual bool end() = 0; // returns if we are at the end of collection
      virtual O next_order_measure() = 0; returns an instance of a class that can be used for ordering
      virtual void visit();
};

class VisitedCollectionA: VisitedCollection<time_t>
{
    public:
       VisitedCollectionA(std::vector<A> &&a): items(std::move(a))
       {
           next_item = items.begin();
       }
       virtual bool end() override { return next_item == items.end(); }
       virtual time_t next_order_meaure() override { return nextItem->timeStamp;}
       virtual void visit() override { std::cout << nextItem->length << std::endl;}

    private:

        std::vector<A>            &items;
        std::vector<A>::iterator  next_item;

        
}
... similar for class B
... could also add a class C, D, etc

Now I can create a collection of VisitedCollection<time_t>, and add VisitedCollectionA, and VisitedCollectionB. This collection of collections would:
```

Start by looking at the return value of the ordering function for the first item in each collection. Which ever one has the smallest value, call it's visitor function. Then find the collection which whose next item has the lowest ordering value. On ties on the ordering function, iterate collection which comes first in the "collection" of collections. Once a collection hits 'end', it's removed from the iteration.

I'm considering rolling my own, but wanted to know if there was already something like this in the standard library. I could even make visit() a lambda, which would allow the VisitedCollectionA types be templates, which take an ordering type and a collection type, that would allow the creation of the main visitor to be initialized with something like

```
{
  VisitedCollection<time_t, std::vector<A>>
  (
   vecA, 
   [](){ return next_item->timeStamp; }, 
   [](const A&a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
  ),
  VisitedCollection<time_t, std::deque<B>>
  (
   deqB, 
   [](){ return next_item->GetTimestamp(); }, 
   [](const B&b) { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
  )
}
```

This feels a bit like a mixture of variant and ranges

Does something like this exist?

Comment: There probably is a solution, but it would help if you described what you want to accomplish rather than how you want to implement it.

Comment: I thought I did give a description of what I want to accomplish. Basically, have multiple collections of objects which have timestamps. I want to "iterate" through all of them in timestamp order, invoking a callback, which is dependent on the type which should be visited next.

I'll try updating the question to give an example up front.

Answer (score 1):

There's no straightforward solution in the C++ std (or any other std, I guess?) but some support for a self-made solution can be found there anyway. Even though suboptimal, it should be easy to understand and rewrite if needed.

First of all, you need const getters (omitted here) and a unified interface for getting timestamps out of the types iterated:

```cpp
time_t timestamp(A const& a) { return a.timeStamp; }
time_t timestamp(B const& b) { return b.GetTimestamp(); }
template<typename... Ts> time_t timestamp(std::variant<Ts...> const& v) {
    return visit([](auto&& e) { return timestamp(e); }, v);
} // see below
```

The basic idea is putting references to all elements into a single container (as variants), sorting and then visiting them:

```cpp
void visit_sorted_timestamps(auto visitor, auto&&... ranges) {
    std::vector<std::variant<
            std::reference_wrapper<std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(ranges)>>...
    >> mixed;
    mixed.reserve((... + size(ranges)));
    (..., mixed.insert(end(mixed), begin(ranges), end(ranges)));
    std::sort(begin(mixed), end(mixed), [](auto&& v1, auto&& v2) {
        return timestamp(v1) < timestamp(v2);
    });
    for (auto&& v: mixed) visit(visitor, v);
}
```

Usage example:

```cpp
int main() {
    visit_sorted_timestamps(Overload{
        [](A const& a) { std::cout << a.length << '\n'; },
        [](B const& b) { std::cout << b.GetName() << '\n'; }
    }, listA, listB);
}
```

If you don't have the lambda "overloading" struct yet, here it goes:

```cpp
template<typename... Fs> struct Overload: Fs... { using Fs::operator()...; };
template<typename... Fs> Overload(Fs...) -> Overload<Fs...>;
```